# Using ratio_to_report analytic

Tags: sql, oracle, function, oracle10g, analytic-functions

I am trying to get the percentage of rows that a set of particular value has.  Best explained by example.  I can do this by each column very simply using ratio-to-report function and over(), but am having issues with multiple groupings

Assume table has 2 columns:

```
column a         column b
1000             some data
1100             some data
2000             some data
1400             some data
1500             some data
```

With the following query, I can get for this domain set, each one is 20% of the total rows

```
select columna, count(*), trunc(ratio_to_report(count(columna)) over() * 100, 2) as perc
from table
group by columna
order by perc desc;
```

However, what I need is for example to determine the percentage & count of the rows that contain 1000, 1400 or 2000;  From looking at it, you can tell its 60%, but need a query to return that.  This needs to be efficient, as the query will be running against millions of rows.  Like I said before, I have this working on a single value and its percentage, but the multiple is what is throwing me.

Seems like I need to be able to put an IN clause somewhere, but the values will not be these specific values each time.  I will need to get the values for the "IN" part of it from another table, if that makes sense.  guess I need some kind of multiple grouping.

Answer (score 1):

Potentially, you're looking for something like

```
SQL> ed
Wrote file afiedt.buf

  1  with x as (
  2    select 1000 a from dual
  3    union all
  4    select 1100 from dual
  5    union all
  6    select 1400 from dual
  7    union all
  8    select 1500 from dual
  9    union all
 10    select 2000 from dual
 11  )
 12  select (case when a in (1000,1400,1500)
 13               then 1
 14               else 0
 15           end) bucket,
 16         count(*),
 17         ratio_to_report(count(*)) over ()
 18    from x
 19   group by (case when a in (1000,1400,1500)
 20               then 1
 21               else 0
 22*          end)
SQL> /

    BUCKET   COUNT(*) RATIO_TO_REPORT(COUNT(*))OVER()
---------- ---------- -------------------------------
         1          3                              .6
         0          2                              .4
```

Comment: this is close to what I am looking for except I cant use the case statements since in reality I have many combinations.  I didnt explain it initially very well.                                                                  I need to add a 2nd table that controls what you basically have in your case statement.

Comment: this is close to what I am looking for except I cant use the case statements since in reality I have many combinations.  I didnt explain it initially very well. I need to use a 2nd table to control basically where you have your case statement

Table2

Column1  Column2
1000       -
1100       2000
1400       1000
2000       -
1500       1000

Results should be:

1000       3      60%
2000       2      40%

So, "bucket" would be column1 where column2 is null
and count/percentage would be made up of rows where column1 is null or column2 points to column1 as a parent

hope that makes more sense

Comment: how do you get the formatting correct ?  I really goofed that up.  In my previous example the numbers are really 2 columns with the - being a null in column 2 for that row, 1000 null, 1100 2000, 1400 1000, 2000 null, 1500 1000 as rows in a 2 column table.   Sorry, but I am not familiar with how to format correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I entirely understand the requirement, but do you need `ratio_to_report` at all? Have a look at the following, and let me know how close this is to what you want, and we can work from there!

T1 is the table containing your sample data

```
create table t1(a primary key) as
   select 1000 as a from dual union all
   select 1100 as a from dual union all
   select 1400 as a from dual union all
   select 1500 as a from dual union all
   select 2000 as a from dual;
```

T2 is the lookup table you mentioned (where you get the list of IDs)

```
create table t2(a primary key) as
   select 1000 as a from dual union all
   select 1400 as a from dual union all
   select 2000 as a from dual;
```

A left join from T1->T2 will return all rows in T1 paired with all matching rows in T2. For each A in T1 that does not exist in your set (T2), the result will be padded with NULL. We can exploit the fact that `COUNT()` doesn't count (hehe) nulls.

```
select count(t1.a) as num_rows
      ,count(t2.a) as in_set
      ,count(t2.a) / count(t1.a) as shr_in_set
  from t1
  left 
  join t2 on(t1.a = t2.a);
```

The result of running the query is:

```
  NUM_ROWS     IN_SET SHR_IN_SET
---------- ---------- ----------
         5          3         ,6
```